# Lower case letters do not work when trying to access a VirtualBox VM through TeamViewer

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, teamviewer

There is a remote Windows 10 computer that I access through TeamViewer from my local Debian 8. Everything works fine. On the remote Windows machine I launch a VirtualBox VM with Linux (Debian 9) inside. Once I try to type something in the VM window some keys do not work. For instance numbers work, uppercase letters work (when I use SHIFT or CAPS LOCK), however lowercase letters just don't work. Why? Mouse works without problems inside and outside of the VM window.

Comment: Lowercase doesn’t work, but you indicated, uppercase does when shift is used.  So nothing is typed when shift isn’t pressed?  Sounds like a TeamViewer problem to me.  What if you connect TeamViewer to the VM and connect directly to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, but the problem disappeared once I have switched from "Bridged" network mode (that I was using till now in VirtualBox VM) to "NAT".

Comment: Also pay attention that you have English keyboard on the remote Windows machine enabled (and not some other language layout).